# Showing nearby specific business offices in table view cells using iphone GPS

Tags: iphone, xcode4, core-location

There are lots of similar questions but my question is different in that sense i got coordinates of my current location in my application.

But now i want to show specific business offices in table view around that coordinates. I know ReverseGeoConding is answer to that but i cant find suitable tutorial or advice on this. How can i implement it.

Please suggest .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse Geocoding will provide you with address information for the coordinates provided.  In order to get businesses around those coordinates, you may want to look into external APIs.  I believe Facebook has a Places API and Foursquare has an API as well.  These may be able to provide you with local business information.